# Solr: Data import handler from IMAP

Tags: solr, imap

I am trying to get Solr to read from an IMAP server, but am not able to get it working.

What I did so far:

a) Added the  entries in solrconfig.xml, for:

- `contrib/dataimporthandler-extras/lib/activation-*`
- `contrib/dataimporthandler-extras/lib/javax.mail-*`
- `contrib/dataimporthandler-extras/lib/gimap-*`
- `dist/solr-dataimporthandler-*`
- `dist/solr-dataimporthandler-extras-*`

b) Created the data import config file, which contains this:

```
<dataConfig>
    <document>
        <entity processor="MailEntityProcessor" protocol="imaps"
                user="..." password="..." host="..."
                fetchMailsSince="2014-06-30 00:00:00"
                batchSize="20" folders="inbox"
                processAttachement="false"
                name="mail_entity"/>
        <field column="subject" name="msubject" />
        <field column="subject" name="subject" />
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

c) Reloaded the core.

Then, when in the Solr Admin GUI and click the “Execute” button with the “mail_entity” selected in the drop-down menu, I get the result “Requests: 0, Fetched: 0, Skipped: 0, Processed: 0”. The raw status contains these status messages:

```
{
    "Total Requests made to DataSource": "0",
    "Total Rows Fetched": "0",
    "Total Documents Processed": "0",
    "Total Documents Skipped": "0",
    "Full Dump Started": "2016-01-11 21:45:34",
    "": "Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents.",
    "Committed": "2016-01-11 21:45:35",
    "Time taken": "0:0:1.512"
}
```

On the IMAP server, I can see that Solr connects to the server and authenticates, but no mails are read and I don’t get any errors either.

The Solr version is 5.3.0.

Any ideas on what I could do to further investigate what is happening or rather not happening?

Comment: Could you check the name of the folder - `inbox` on the imap server?

Comment: Yes, sure. I logged in via IMAP, issued a `LIST "" *` and got a list, which contained (among other entries) `LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" INBOX` and `LIST (\NoInferiors \UnMarked) "/" Spam`. I tested with both folders, with and without leading slash (I am not a Java guy and therefore don’t know how Solr prefers the mailbox). Result: exactly the same, i.e.: nothing imported, no errors.

Comment: Did you honor capitalization i.e. INBOX as against inbox?

Comment: Yes. Initially, I used “inbox”, but after retriving the list of folders/namespaces, I used “INBOX” and “Spam”.